# send local image upload to database android

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

I can change image with local picker (not camera) and set it to imageview (profile_image) like this :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            //selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            //Utils.log("selectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);
            Utils.log("selectedImageUri: " + selectedImageUri);
            profile_image.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            String id = selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            final String imageOrderBy = null;

            Uri uri = getUri();
            String selectedImagePath = "path";

            Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(uri, imageColumns,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "="+id, null, imageOrderBy);

            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                selectedImagePath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                new LocalImageUpload().execute(selectedImagePath);
            }
            Utils.log("selectedImagePath:" + selectedImagePath); // use selectedImagePath
        }else{
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Utils.log("DatabaseUtils:" + DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // returns null
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I got `selectedImageUri` with `Utils.log("selectedImageUri: " + selectedImageUri);`, but I got `null` when `log Utils.log("selectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);`

Update: I change like that and already got selectedImagePath. commented old selectedImagePath.

So I want to upload image to database after `profile_image.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);` , how to upload local image picker to database? I mean the background proccess POST code?

Comment: make sure you have given READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and also you are selecting image form gallery itself.

Comment: already put it on androidmanifest

Comment: This post can help you to upload image to database, http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: @NigamPatro, that is what I looking for, thank you. this is the correct answer. Sorry for long time to reply because I need to check it first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below one ?

**Pass Uri** as **argument** in below **function** and get **Path** from **Uri**.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI (Uri contentUri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
       path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Now set **Bitmap** on **ImageView** using below code:

```
String mRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(your_uri);
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mRealPath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

**Edit:**

Now you have to **pass** an **argument** for your **Async Task**:

```
new LocalImageUpload().execute(mRealPath);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I got the image path (update the code) and now I am searching how to POST it to database.

Comment: @carijawaban, I have edited my answer, please check.

Comment: yes, like that new LocalImageUpload().execute(mRealPath); and already found background task to upload to database.

Comment: @carijawaban, then what do you need from my end ?